# WooCommerce StoreFront child theme - How to remove title on homepage

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce, hook

Do you know any hook or filter to remove the title on the frontpage of StoreFront theme?

I try several solutions but nothing works. I use a theme child of Storefront (Stationery by Woothemes).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you using static front page. Or you have any template for it.

Comment: FrontPage/stationery have a template for homepage, so it's a static page which have a "homepage" template.

Comment: have you tried to hide title for this page using css.

Comment: No because I really want to remove it from HTML, not only hide it with css, it will be my last option.

Comment: Have you tried this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/storefront-title-toggle/

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have tried so we don't have to suggest things you've already done and/or point out where you've gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this code to `functions.php`:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
   remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header' );
}
```

This should remove everything between (and including):

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <?php
        storefront_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
    ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

Comment: Thank you!
It works perfectly, yesterday I try the same code but with is_home().
Just a correction: it's "is_front_page()".
Thank you again!!!

Comment: Yes, those are confusing [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/#the-front-page). is_home() returns TRUE on the main posts (blog) page, whereas is_frontpage() is TRUE on either the main posts page or the main static page (depending on what option you've chosen in Settings->Reading)

Answer (score 1):

I googled for more details. Please try this

```
if ( is_page('page id') )
{
      add_filter( 'the_title', '__return_false' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying all examples here and in other posts and it worked after to run the remove_action inside the init hook, like this:

```
function wc_hide_page_title() {
    remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wc_hide_page_title');
```